# How to automate in-browser actions

Tags: browser, webui

very out of my element here but trying to find a solution. Currently, I am stuck with only one option to get a CSV file of some data, and that is by clicking on an EXPORT button from the Web UI of a webapp my company uses.

This really puts a kink in the works for automating and programatically setting everything up. How can I devise a script or maybe a plugin or something that can automatically do this action for me (clicking the export button) and be able to also schedule the action. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use AutoHotKey. It's a tool to automate UI in general.

Or you could try Selenium + Geckodriver. It is in browser automation, but I don't know if Export is supported.